# Background location permission auto-added in Android with flutter location plugin

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, flutter-dependencies

I recently added the Flutter [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) plugin to allow my app to use GPS. Everything is working as expected on iOS and App Store, but when building for Android (targetSdkVersion 29 / API level 29) and uploading to Google Play it tells me that the background location permission is present. I can verify that by looking in the build where the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

line is added to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

However, my app doesn't use location in the background, and I just can't find out how I remove this permission that is being automatically added by the location plugin.

The only code that uses location plugin is this line I have in a method:

```
LocationData userLocation = await new Location().getLocation();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The permission is introduced by the location plugin. If you go to its manifest you'll find the following requested permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

To remove it add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
                     tools:node="remove"/>
```

to your apps Manifest.